# How to beat the Hermit in Half-Minute Hero?

Tags: half-minute-hero

In the Hero 30 mission "The Turtle and the Hermit", the hermit offers some new gear to you, if you beat him (once he's "taught your everything he knows"). The problem is, in this battle he's the toughest he's ever been. And since he's the only thing that gives you XP in this mission, there's no way to grind yourself stronger.

How can I beat the hermit? Is it choices I make in the mission? Is it about equipment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And the very next evening I solved the problem.

Once you rescue the hermit, he will offer to train you. By beating him over and over (he isn't fighting with his real power, so you won't take damage and beat him and his fireballs with a single hit), you can gain the levels needed to beat the stage.
There are also two apprentices of the hermit hidden in the stage. Each will give you one of the hermits favourite foods and giving those to the hermit will make him stronger, thus allowing you to level up faster.

However, if and only if (this is what I failed to fully explore) you give him both of these food items, he will stop training with you at level 40. If, however you give him only one of the foods or neither, you can keep leveling beyond this, up to around level 60 where you'll start to run out of money to buy more time.

What I found was that giving him neither foods slowed the leveling up process so much, you didn't have time to get to level 60 before running out of money. But by giving him one of the foods, training untill I was level 60 and then (finding and) giving him the second food item, he would stop training me, challenge me and I was able to beat him.

And for completeness sake, my gear was Crimson Robe, Horned Helm, Spike Mace, Flash Shield and Bigfoot.